# Getting TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple, can't figure out why

Tags: python

Read the other answers to this but couldn't quite figure out how to apply them to my problem:

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dice = [0]*5
        self.rollAll()
    def roll(self, which):
        for pos in enumerate(which):
            self.dice[pos] = random.randrange(1,7)
    def rollAll(self):
        self.roll(range(5))
    def values(self):
        return self.dice[:]
    def counts(self):
        # Create counts list
        counts = [0] * 7
        for value in self.dice:
            counts[value] = counts[value] + 1
        # score the hand
```

Don't get what's causing this error - I've gleaned from other posts like this that it has something to do with the way I've typed my self.dice position line, but again, can't figure out *what exactly* is wrong.   Can any of you help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    for pos in enumerate(which):
        self.dice[pos] = random.randrange(1,7)
```

enumerate returns a tuple of (index, value) that you need to unpack:

```
    for idx, pos in enumerate(which):
        self.dice[idx] = random.randrange(1,7)
```

Comment: I think they may want to omit `enumerate` entirely; the example for `rollAll` is passing the `range` defining the positions to roll, so the index isn't the important thing; presumably you could call `.roll((3,2,5))` and it would roll 3, 2 and 5 in that order (using the index would mean it would roll 0, 1 and 2, which doesn't seem right).

Comment: Yes, I agree we ought to be able to do that @ShadowRanger; In fact I first had a suggestion to iterate directly over the values of "which", but because it is unclear whet exactly "which" represents, I removed that suggestion.